# Java apachi poi gives wrong value for only few fields

Tags: apache-poi

I am using java apchi poi for a little complicated excel sheet.
It works all OK , but only 2 or 3 values are getting wrong , dont underatand why .

for example in the attached screenhsot , I am getting data for all this March column,
for ALL of the rows i get CORRECT answer , ONLY the 1st row's value not getting correct ,
I am struggling to find why , but not getting any clue .

If i was doing something wrong it shouldnt give me correct answer for other rows .. thats why its really hard to trace,

Can i get any clue or any idea to trace this problem

[image]

[image: gives]

[image]

Comment: Seems `apache poi` evaluator evaluates this formula different from `Excel` in this special case. Formula is `E7/(A7-A6+1)*(EOMONTH(A6,0)-A6+1)`. What exactly is in cells `E7`, `A7` and `A6`?

Comment: I added picture which displays the E7, A7,A6 , Also before evaulation my cell, i Also checked the values of these E7, A7, A6 (cell.getNumericCellValue()/ cell.getDateValue()) ,  And those values were also Correct

Comment: I cannot see `A6` and `A7` in your pictures. Also I cannot see if 705,592 is the exact value in `E7` maybe the number format rounds it. So I cannot reproducing your issue. For me it works using a minimal example using the formula `E7/(A7-A6+1)*(EOMONTH(A6,0)-A6+1)`.

Comment: oh sorry, somehow the picture was not uploaded , Uploaded Again

Comment: Cannot reproducing. For me in a minimal example having that values in `A6`, `A7` and `E7` and the formula in `F6` the formula evaluates to `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [55907.56284153005]` and numeric cell value is 55907.56284153005 after evaluation. This is exactly what `Excel` evaluates too.

Comment: thanks for your time , Actually i got this idea from you , to make a new small excel for only these values, I did a test and Yes its correct for me too , But now its mor confusing, Why its not correct in the Real excel , what can i do to find or fix it

Comment: You would need detecting what is difference between your working test case and the not working case.